# Problem with AlertView in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I have a tab bar app.  During the applicationDidFinishLaunching method I have the app check for some files and then display an alertview if the files exist.

I have all the code working except that the alertview will not appear after the tabBarcontroller is showing.

The sequence of events is

1. splashscreen shows
2. window dims (this tells me the alert is attempting to show)
3. the app pauses (it's waiting for me to press a button a I have a CFRunloop running.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Needs code. We can't help without knowing anything about the code.

Comment: got it figured out but the code was just to show an alert pretty basic code [alert show] and i had tested all the code separately from another function;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

thanks for the hints but I figured it out.

It needed a performSelectorOnMainThread  wait(NO)

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(checkDownloads) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

on the main calling function inside applicationDidFinishLaunching:

to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `performSelector` with a delay, so that when the splash is done, the UIAertView will show.

Or display the alert in your root view.

Comment: Hi I did use   [alertView performSelector:@selector(show) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];   but it made no difference on it's own it needed my answer also (mainThread)